# Find the equation of the circle passing through two points (4,4) and (-2.-2) with radius 4

Tags: circles

I am trying to solve this question but i cannot seem to find the center (h,k). I know i have to use the equation of circle form '(x-h)^2+(x-k)^2=r^2' and after that form to solution of the 2 point given and simultaneous equations them. I got the answer for that which is h+k=2 and that is where i got stuck. Please anyone help me with this. i also post my working as well. [Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTo4k.png)

Comment: Please, use MathJax to format your question https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference:

Answer (score 1):

Since the distance between $(4,4)$ and $(-2,-2)$ is equal to $6\sqrt2$, which is greater that $8$, the problem has no solution.

Comment: So the final answer is 'indeterminate'?

Comment: @EugeneLee As far as I am concerned, the final answer is “The problem has no solution.”

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $$M(x_M,y_M)$$ the coordinates of the miodpoint of the circle, then solve
$$(4-x_M)^2+(4-y_M)^2=16$$
$$(-2-x_M)^2+(-2-y_M)^2=16$$
for $$x_M,y_M$$
Subtracting both equation we get
$$-x_M-y_M+2=0$$
and now you can calculate $$x_M,y_M$$ substituing in one equation from above.

Comment: That is what i did in my working (which i post) https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTo4k.png. I got stuck at that part ' h+k=2 '

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you are missing is that there are two circles satisfying this and two possible centers, one on each side of the line through (4, 4) and (-2, -2).

The perpendicular bisector of a secant line of a circle always passes through the center of the circle.  (4, 4) and (-2, -2) are points on the circle and the line passing through both is y= x.  The midpoint is (1, 1) and the perpendicular has slope -1 so the perpendicular bisector is y- 1= -(x- 1) or y= -x+ 2.

We want a point on that line such that its distance from both (4, 4) and (-2, -2) is 4.  That is, we want $\sqrt{(x- 4)^2+ (y- 4)^2}= \sqrt{(x- 4)^2+ (-x+ 2- 4)^2}= \sqrt{(x- 4)^2+ (-x+ 2)^2}= 4$.  Then  $(x- 4)^2+ (-x+ 2)^2= x^2- 8x+ 16+ x^2- 4x+ 4= 2x^2- 12x+ 20= 16$.  $x^2- 6x+ 2= x^2- 6x+ 9- 9+ 2= (x- 3)^2- 7= 0$.  $x- 3= \pm\sqrt{7}$ so $x= 3\pm{7}$.  If $x= 3\pm\sqrt{7}$ then $y= -(3\pm\sqrt{7})+ 2= -1\pm\sqrt{7}$.  The two possible centers of the circle are $(3+ \sqrt{7}, -1- \sqrt{7})$ and $(3- \sqrt{7}, -1+ \sqrt{7})$